# Emacs keybindings in zsh not working (Ctrl-A, Ctrl-E)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh

My Emacs keybindings in `zsh` are not working (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>). I use `zsh` on OS X.

They might be bound to some other thing. I'm currently using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

And my `.zshrc` is over [here](https://github.com/Takehiro-Adachi/dotfiles/blob/master/.zshrc).

[image]

Comment: @rene Done! thx for the advice! :D

Comment: From the screenshot I gather you are on Mac OS X? I have the same problem there in terminal. Ctrl+A/E/K are already taken in that OS (for use in text fields in the GUI), which might explain this.

Comment: @Henno really? Im using zsh atm, and when i use bash, the ctrl+a(go to the first char of line) and ctrl+e(go to the end of the line) works fine. but when i use zsh, it goes like the screenshot. so i think its an problem about zsh, not the OS :(

Comment: @TakehiroAdachi your fixed worked for me too!

Comment: @Henno Great :D!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I got the problem solved. Looks like oh-my-zsh was overriding the default keybindings.

When I added the below line at the end of my `.zshrc`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> worked:

```
bindkey -e
```

Comment: great, worked for me too!

Comment: fixed my problem too.  FWIW, I also found the guilty party in my `~/.zshrc`:
````# Lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
HISTFILE=~/.histfile  
HISTSIZE=1000  
SAVEHIST=1000  
bindkey -v ````  So it looks like it's Apple being "helpful".

Comment: If one of the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables contain the string 'vi' when the shell starts up then it will be 'viins', otherwise it will be 'emacs'.

Answer (score 9):

Generally speaking, you can find the code of a key by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and the key. You can then use this key with `bindkey` to map it to a `zsh` keyboard functionality (e.g. `beginning-of-line`).

In your specific case that would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

Then you can put the code in your `.inputrc`, the system `/etc/inputrc`, or your `.zshrc` like this:

```
bindkey '^A' beginning-of-line
bindkey '^E' end-of-line
```

This works for other keys too. For instance, I had some trouble with <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>.

You should be able to use this trick in any terminal session : tty,